# How to access the EPerson that triggered a curation task (from within the task)?

Tags: dspace

How can I access the `EPerson` that triggered a curation task from within the task in DSpace 6?

I tried:

```
currentUser = Curator.curationContext().getCurrentUser()
```

But this seems to always be `null`.

**Background:**
Only users (`EPerson`s) that are part of a certain `Group` should be allowed to execute the curation task. So I try to get the user that triggered the task and plan to compare it to the group that is allowed to use the task. Or is there a completely different approach to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could override the perform(Context ctx, String id) method from abstract class AbstractCurationTask. Then you should be able to get the user with ctx.getCurrentUser().

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately this method seems to never get called. Any ideas?

Comment: If that method does not get used then you might have to adapt the class that calls the perform(DSpaceObject dso) method to use the perform(Context ctx, String id) instead (or implement your own perform(Context ctx, DSpaceObject dso) method in AbstractCurationTask and use that one). Hopefully this class has a Context object. If not then you will have to adapt a few more classes to pass along the Context object.